# Why Jenkins says in SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed. ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s)

Tags: jenkins

I'm trying to connect to Windows agent use SSh(Launch agent agents via SSH)
Jenkins master(in  Linux)
log:
[SSH] Opening SSH connection to 192.168.0.122:22.
[SSH] SSH host key matches key seen previously for this host. Connection will be allowed.
ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key(s) for my_bot (**********)
 [SSH] Authentication failed.
Authentication failed.
Launch failed - cleaning up connection
[SSH] Connection closed.
I tried to add key to  authorized_keys.. but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

When ssh says "SSH host key" it means the keys in known_hosts.
Check .ssh/known_hosts to see that key.
Although "Connection will be allowed" implies this is not a problem for you.
So ignore that part of the error message.

Your real problem is "ERROR: Server rejected the 1 private key"...

Is they key exchanged ok?
Private key needs to be in jenkins. Also check file permissions.
Public key needs to be on server side. Probably .ssh/authorized_keys. Also check file permissions. Ssh will not allow keys to be used if permissions on .ssh or files contained inside are too open.

More information is needed to help solve the question:

1. In your question please show the ssh command you use - the full command - do you specify key with -i parameter ?
2. From jenkins command-line, can you ssh to the host using the same ssh command ?
3. Do ls -al on jenkins home .ssh dir and on server side .ssh dir to check permissions.
4. To get more verbose/debug information add -v or -vv or -vvv to your ssh command.
   Also look at ssh logs on server side if possible.
5. In your question you could tidy up the log messages.

Same error seen on this question here and I can see they did chown 744 .ssh/authorized_keys in dockerfile which is the wrong way to set permissions for an authorized_keys file.
https://superuser.com/questions/1403715/why-i-am-getting-error-server-rejected-the-1-private-key-error-on-setting-up-s/1443503#1443503